# Is it possible to place a logo on HTML5 video?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am using `HTML5` video to stream a web camera and I am wondering is it possible to place a logo inside `HTML5` video stream?

```
<div id="streaming">
        <video id="webcam" autoplay></video>
    </div>
```

Comment: You might find what you look for here: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

Comment: Do you wish that the logo is part of the video frames or do you accept an overlay positioned absolutely over the video element?

Comment: I accept overlay positioned over the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by adding an image element into the html­*'s* body section and placing it accordingly *(which suits the best for your need)* using css.

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```css
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="streaming">
        <video id="webcam" src="https://istack.000webhostapp.com/psy.mp4" height="219" autoplay></video>
        <img src="https://istack.000webhostapp.com/yt.png" width="40" class="logo">
    </div>
</body>
```